# Using sharepoint getfile output in filereader

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, base64, documents

I would like to convert a sharepoint document file to a base 64 format by using File reader. But the problem is that when I fetch the sharepoint document by Get_file (). It returns the file in sp.File object. But to use it in Filereader I need it to be either F
ile object or Blob. Any help or pointers appriciated

After getting the itemd from the sharepoint document i use this code to call filereader and get a type mismatch error.
I get the sharepoint Item from document library and then use this:

```
function(items){
    for(var i = 0; i < items.get_count();i++) {
        var file = items.get_item(i).get_file();
        alert(file);
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        //rest of my code
    }
}
```

Comment: Please help the community help you by providing the code you are using!

Comment: After getting the itemd from the sharepoint document i use this code to call filereader and get a typemissmatch error function(items){
        for(var i = 0; i < items.get_count();i++) {
            var file = items.get_item(i).get_file();
            alert(file);
            var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.readAsDataURL(file);
             ---rest of my code}

Comment: Its not returning a file contents, just its metadata. Try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37322986/read-content-of-sp-file-object-as-text-using-jsom